# Why didn't Hitler decide to wait until after winning WW2 to implement the final solution?

Tags: world-war-two, hitler, holocaust

My question is based on the following assumptions.

1. Hitler believed he will eventually win WW2.
2. Hitler wanted to implement the final solution as part of the Nazi ideology.
3. Implementing the final solution required resources (manpower, materials, etc) that could have been otherwise used towards the German war effort.

Why didn't Hitler and other top Nazi leaders decide to wait until after winning, or nearly winning, WW2 before starting the implementation of the final solution? Why was he willing to accept the "cost" at the detriment of the war effort? Did he see any immediate "practical advantages" leading him to believe that the final solution has a positive contribution to the German war efforts?

To be clear, this question solely deals with Hitler's and the Nazi high command decision making process and priorities during WW2.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please research those assumptions.   I'm not sure that the assumptions are generally shared.  If I recall correctly, the ["functionalism/intentionalism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functionalism%E2%80%93intentionalism_debate) debate is both subtle and relevant.

Comment: Probably not answerable unless you know a good medium :-)  Also supposes that Hitler was actually capable of making rational, long-term plans, which I suspect is not really borne out by evidence.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace thank you for pointing this out. I did not know about this debate and find it interesting. For the purpose this question, I either assume the intentionalist viewpoint, or replace my 2nd assumption by the much weaker assumption "Hitler knew about the final solution and it was within his power to stop/postpone it". I believe the question still makes sense.

Comment: @jamesqf Yes, my question has to do with Hitler's rationality, for assuming intentionalism, it seems more rational to prioritize immediate goals such as winning the war and the preservation of the Nazi regime over long-term ideological goals.

Comment: @Arie: The problem is in the assumption of rationality.  We can see a mild parallel in for instance the current responses to the Coronavirus.  It would be rational to listen to medical experts and follow their advice, but we see many people - from high elected officials down to street protestors - trying to pretend the problem doesn't exist, or proposing "wishfull thinking" solutions.

Comment: One can also conjecture that Hitler regarded killing all Jews in Europe as more important than winning the war.

Comment: Have you ever hated someone with every fiber of your being ?

Comment: Question has merit, current mainstream history ties beginning of final solution to Wannsee Conference, which happened almost in the middle of the war, after Barbarossa failed, US entered the war and Operation Crusader happened in North Africa. Thus motivation for starting extermination fairly lately, when things started to get worse, seems as legitimate question.

Answer (score 1):

> Hitler believed he will eventually win WW2

The premise of your question is wrong. Hitler never [wanted](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/32805/what-was-nazi-germanys-end-goal/32809#32809) a World War, he had already *experienced losing* a two front world war once and by the time they started to implement the death camps for real, it was pretty clear that they would likely lose.

Did they just give up when it did not look good? Certainly not. Did anybody *talk* about it not looking good? Uh, certainly not, that would have been "defeatism" and punishable by death. But don't assume people were blind to the facts just because they did not roll over and accept the inevitable.

For a closer look, I recommend higher ranking military commanders talking in captivity (and being wiretapped) and especially higher ranking military in private conversations. In the middle of the Barbarossa campaign, months from the winter debacle, General Heinrici wrote to his wife, which properties to sell and which to keep, because some would lose in value quickly after allied bombers would be in reach. People were not blind to the fact that Barbarossa had been a gamble and it had been lost.

So Hitler had no grand plans for world domination. We don't know whether he actually believed they would win the war they had on their hands, but people with some realistic viewpoints did not and there is no reason to believe Hitler did not know this. The fact that he did propagate the "Endsieg" until the very end is hardly surprising given the fact that defeat meant his certain personal death. You don't give up fights that end with your own death, no matter how slim the chances. And you certainly don't tell your team all is lost if you want them to fight for you.

So the more realistic leaders did not believe it would all turn out well and others were consumed by their hatred anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and pointing out the problem with my 1st assumption. I now realize my question may be poorly formulated. However I think the essence of the question still makes sense - and even more so given your answer - how did Hitler rationalize prioritizing the final solution over the general war effort?